# FileNotFoundError: [Errono 2]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new at python and I have been trying to do some basic stuff with it.

I cannot manage to open the file using a python file for some reason. When I was in PowerShell and ran python, using the same line, it works.

```
print("Detected new file: " + inFilename)
    print(os.getcwd())
    if open('c:/users/charles phung pc/desktop/pop/unprocessed/'+inFilename):
        print(inFilename+' is opened!')
```

This is not the only style of absolute path I've tried, I've tried these as well:

> `C:\\Users\\Charles Phung PC\\Desktop\\PoP\\file`
>
> `C:/Users/Charles Phung PC/Desktop/PoP/file`
>
> `/Users/Charles Phung PC/Desktop/PoP/file`

Console log:

[image: In the stack]

On other lines, I was able to create new files, write to new files. I just could not get this to work.

Also, it works when I run those lines on the console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. It contains the exception handling as well.

**Code:**

```
import os

for file_name in os.listdir("."):  # Search in the current directory. You can write: os.getcwd() instead of "."
    if not os.path.isfile(file_name):  # If the found element is not a file, do nothing.
        continue
    print("Detected new file: {}".format(file_name))
    print(os.getcwd())
    file_path = os.path.join("c:", "users", "charles phung pc", "desktop", "pop", "unprocessed", file_name)  # Append the correct path. 
    try:
        with open(file_path, "r") as opened_file:
            print("{} file is opened!".format(file_path))
    except FileNotFoundError as file_not_found_exc:  # Handle the FileNotFoundError exception. In this case the script does nothing, get the next file.
        print("File not found: {}".format(file_not_found_exc))
    except Exception as unexpected_exc:  # Handle the other exceptions. If there is other exception then the script will fail. 
        print("Unexpected exception: {}".format(unexpected_exc))
        raise unexpected_exc
```

**Output** (if I use a wrong path (yours) in `os.path.join()`)

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Detected new file: profiles_settings.xml
/home/milanbalazs/test/opencv
File not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/users/charles phung pc/desktop/pop/unprocessed/profiles_settings.xml'
Detected new file: R_User_Library.xml
/home/milanbalazs/test/opencv
...
...
...
```

**Output** (if I use a correct path. In my case: `file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name)`)

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Detected new file: second_test.py
/home/milanbalazs/test/opencv
second_test.py file is opened!
Detected new file: test.py
/home/milanbalazs/test/opencv
test.py file is opened!
Detected new file: 69542278_1359592257526566_7093966790966902784_n.jpg
/home/milanbalazs/test/opencv
69542278_1359592257526566_7093966790966902784_n.jpg file is opened!
...
...
...
```